# Learn Python the hard way exercise 5 EC4

Tags: python

I am trying to write some variables that convert inches and pounds to centimeters and kilos. I'm trying to work out the math in Python and having some trouble.

After struggling a while, I managed to do this in Python:

```
inches = 19
centimeters = inches * 2.54
print "%r inches equals %r centimeters." % (inches, centimeters)


pounds = 180
kilos = pounds /2.2
print "%r pounds equals %r kilos." % (pounds, kilos)
```

While the inch to cm calculation works great, I get an incorrect result on pounds to kilos (e.g. wolframalpha says it should be 81.65kg.)

**What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this in order to get the right result?**

Thanks!

Comment: Felix is right, the actual value is: 2.20462262

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using a Python version before 3.x, `/` is integer division, not float division, which will cause errors. You can do `from __future__ import division` to get the 3.x behaviour in 2.x (and use `//` for integer division).

Comment: @Lattyware: It's integer devision if all operands are integers, but that's not the case here. Still worth mentioning though.

Comment: @FelixKling Wow, I jumped on that one without thinking, that is entirely true. Disregard my comment then.

Comment: @Lattyware "if you're using a Python version before 3.x" - not if about it; the OP is using `print` as a statement.

Comment: @lvc True, but I tend to state it specifically so that people looking at the post using other versions don't get confused. That said, it's irrelevant anyway, as Fleix Kling pointed out, it's not an issue here.

Comment: @digEmAll The actual value is a repeating decimal with a period of 24288. Use the exact definition of 1 pound = 0.45359237 kilograms if accuracy is needed.

Comment: This question should be reopened now that it has been edited for clarity. The most generous explanation is that the way the beginning was worded was confusing for people and they were missing the actual question below. A less generous explanation which seems more likely based on the active comments history, is that people were being much less helpful or friendly than we typically expect here. This shouldn't have been closed as it is not "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" and in fact can certainly be answered. Great example of data type issues as lively comments show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 pound = 0.45359237 kilograms

So your code has to be:

```
pounds = 180
kilos = pounds * 0.45359237
print "%r pounds equals %r kilos." % (pounds, kilos)
```

And you get the correct result.

Comment: Yes and his code uses 2.2 which isn't accurate enough (btw. reciprocal mul is faster)

Comment: @david The real problem is OP didn't say what the 'wierd results' are. Off by a little? Or totally unrelated.

Comment: I tested it, they were off by `0.1715552181818083`, so I opened a conversion table and looked up the correct/accurate number and added a little performance boost (maybe not noticable in this case, but it's important when you do speed critical stuff)

Comment: @joshp 1 pound is defined as exactly 0.45359237 kilograms and this constant should always be used for accuracy. **The reciprocal is a repeating decimal with a period of 24288**